# Why does unique_ptr have the deleter as a type parameter while shared_ptr doesn't?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, type-erasure

The [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) template has two parameters: the type of the pointee, and the type of the deleter. This second parameter has a default value, so you usually just write something like `std::unique_ptr<int>`.

The [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) template has only one parameter though: the type of the pointee. But you can use a custom deleter with this one too, even though the deleter type is not in the class template. The usual implementation uses type erasure techniques to do this.

Is there a reason the same idea was not used for `std::unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Part of the reason is that `shared_ptr` needs an explicit control block anyway for the ref count and sticking a deleter in isn't that big a deal on top. `unique_ptr` however doesn't require any additional overhead, and adding it would be unpopular- it's supposed to be a zero-overhead class. `unique_ptr` is supposed to be static.

You can always add your own type erasure on top if you want that behaviour- for example, you can have `unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>`, something that I have done in the past.

Comment: +1. Type erasure isn't a "good thing", it's more like a necessary evil. If you can get away with a simpler solution, then you should. `unique_ptr` is a much simpler and lighter-weight smart pointer than `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @DeadMG: I don't get the "`unique_ptr` is supposed to be static" part. What does that mean -- specifically, the usage of "static"?

Comment: @Jon: It means that it should not resolve the functionality used dynamically- the compiler should statically resolve all calls involved. This enables it to compete against your momma's best home-rolled C code w.r.t. performance in all respects.

Comment: @DeadMG: So, "static" in this context is a weaker version of "zero-overhead" (which I read as "static and also no bigger mem footprint"). That clears it up, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to have the best of both worlds? For certain deleter types (including the default), there is only one possible *value* for the deleter, and therefore no memory overhead. But, for certain deleter types, the `unique_ptr` would be expanded to include the value of the deleter. I guess this might be complex, and might have required a different design of the class.

Answer (score 4):

From ***C++ Primer (5th Edition)***, Chapter 16.1.6 - Efficiency and Flexibility

> The obvious difference between shared_ptr and unique_ptr is the strategy they
> use in managing the pointer they hold—one class gives us shared ownership;
> the other owns the pointer that it holds. This difference is essential to
> what these classes do.
>
> These classes also differ in how they let users override their default
> deleter. We can easily override the deleter of a shared_ptr by passing a
> callable object when we create or reset the pointer. In contrast, the type of
> the deleter is part of the type of a unique_ptr object. Users must supply
> that type as an explicit template argument when they define a unique_ptr. As
> a result, it is more complicated for users of unique_ptr to provide their own
> deleter.
>
> **By binding the deleter at compile time, unique_ptr avoids the run-time cost
> of an indirect call to its deleter. By binding the deleter at run time,
> shared_ptr makes it easier for users to override the deleter.**

Answer (score 2):

Another reason, in addition to the one pointed out by DeadMG, would be that it's possible to write

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> a(new int[100]);
```

and `~unique_ptr` will call the *correct* version of `delete` (via `default_delete<_Tp[]>`) thanks to specializing for both `T` and `T[]`.

Comment: I don't see how that changes much. You could specialise for `T[]` without the deleter parameter.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible, but less elegant and less flexible, as it would be hardcoded inside `unique_ptr`, not the deleter. Note that you could plug in a `foo_delete` which could do something completely different, too. Having a deleter that manually runs the destructor and then marks objects for later reclamation by a GC would be a fun thing, for example. The smart pointer wouldn't need to know at all.

Comment: Just as shared_ptr doesn't need to know. You could do the same type erasure tricks when specializing for `T[]`, no?

Comment: Not sure... maybe, maybe not. The same line of code using `shared_ptr` fails to compile, which shows that `shared_ptr` apparently _doesn't_ specialize. Assuming that the standard library writers don't _randomly_ include/exclude key functionality which is easy to incorporate on a how-do-you-feel-today base, it seems that there must be a considerable, non-obvious hindrance somewhere.

Comment: @Damon: `T[]` specialization is not at all key functionality. I don't even know why it's in `unique_ptr`. We already have `std::vector<T>` for this purpose.

Comment: @DeadMG: Are you suggesting that `unique_ptr` should not have a specialization for `T[]`? I think the alternative would be very undesirable. As far as `vector<T>` goes, it is not a drop in replacement for `unique_ptr<T[]>` which I can see some (albeit not common) uses for, the first of which is legacy code reasons.