# Is there a convenient way to get unique_ptr to automagically have a deleter like shared_ptr?

Tags: c++

[`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) has a nifty templated constructor that automagically creates the right deleter for its given type (constructor #2 in that link).

Until just now, I (erroneously) thought [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) had a similar constructor, but when I ran the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

// Notice nothing is virtual
struct Foo
{
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
    ~Bar() { std::cout << "Bar\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "shared_ptr:\n";
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> p(new Bar()); // prints Bar Foo
    }

    {
        std::cout << "unique_ptr:\n";
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> p(new Bar()); // prints Foo
    }
}
```

[I was surprised to learn that `unique_ptr` doesn't call `Bar`'s destructor.](http://ideone.com/u8d2OO)

What's a clean, simple, and correct way to create a `unique_ptr` that has the correct deleter for its given pointer? Especially if I want to store a whole list of these (i.e. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`), which means that they all must have a heterogeneous type?

(pardon the poor title; feel free to suggest a better one)

Comment: `unique_ptr`'s deleter is in its type. If you make a vector of `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`, then they are all going to use `std::default_delete<Foo>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829576/why-does-unique-ptr-have-the-deleter-as-a-type-parameter-while-shared-ptr-doesn

Comment: I think the problem is with your class, not `std::unique_ptr`. Your destructor needs to be virtual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
{
    std::cout << "unique_ptr<Bar, void(void*)>:\n";
    std::unique_ptr<Foo, void(*)(void*)> p(
        new Bar(), [](void*p) -> void { delete static_cast<Bar*>( p ); }
        ); // prints Bar Foo
}
```

A main problem with this approach is that `unique_ptr` supports conversion to logical "pointer to base class", but that the standard does not guarantee that conversion to `void*` will then yield the same address. In practice that's only a problem if the base class is non-polymorphic while the derived class is polymorphic, introducing a vtable ptr and thus possibly changing the memory layout a bit. But in that possible-but-not-likely situation the cast back in the deleter would yield an incorrect pointer value, and bang.

So, the above is not formally safe with respect to such conversions.

---

To do roughly the same as a `shared_ptr` does (`shared_ptr` supports conversions to logical pointer-to-base), you would need to store also the original `void*` pointer, along with the deleter.

---

In general, when you control the the topmost base class, make its destructor virtual.

That takes care of everything.

Comment: For the problematic scenario, how about double `static_cast` - cast the `void *` to `Foo *` first and then to `Bar *`?

Comment: @T.C. The problem is that the deleter doesn't know the pointer type that was passed to the `void*`. Depending on the type it can point to different addresses. But now that you set me thinking about it, the problem is just that `void*` discards too much information. I think all would be OK with `Foo*` argument type instead, then casted down to `Bar*` in the deleter. Or, is there a problem with that? It's a bit late in the day for me.

Comment: The pointer passed to the deleter is not always useful, even if the types are OK. Sometimes static_cast can be impossible, for example with virtual inheritance (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484913/why-cant-static-cast-be-used-to-down-cast-when-virtual-inheritance-is-involved). I think the only really robust solution is for the deleter to remember the original pointer value (as was returned from `new`). This means the deleter formally ignores its argument, and therefore it may as well be `void*`. Finally, once you pay this memory 'price', you can also add a `deep_copy` at no extra cost.

Answer (score 7):

You should make the destructor of `Foo` `virtual`. That is good practice regardless of whether you use `unique_ptr` or not. That will also take care the problem that you are dealing with.

Comment: I agree that's what should be done, but in this case I can't change the classes