# how to pass custom deleter to std::unique_ptr using std::bind

Tags: c++

How to pass a custom deleter to `std::unique_ptr` using `std::bind`. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct Sample
{
};
// Memory Pool Dummy Kind of Implementation
template<typename T>
class MemoryPool
{
public:
    T * AcquireMemory()
    {
        std::cout << "ACQUIRING MEMORY\n";
        return (new T());
    }
    void ReleaseMemory(T * ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "RELEASING MEMORY\n";
        delete ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MemoryPool<Sample>> memoryPoolPtr = std::make_shared<
            MemoryPool<Sample>>();
    std::shared_ptr<Sample> p3(memoryPoolPtr->AcquireMemory(),
            std::bind(&MemoryPool<Sample>::ReleaseMemory, memoryPoolPtr.get(),
                    std::placeholders::_1));

    std::cout << p3.use_count() << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr<MemoryPool<Sample>> un = std::make_unique<MemoryPool<Sample>>();
// getting compiler error for the below line
    std::unique_ptr<Sample> unq(un->AcquireMemory(), std::bind(&MemoryPool<Sample>::ReleaseMemory, un.get(),
                    std::placeholders::_1));

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting `error: no matching function for call to 'std::unique_ptr<Sample>::unique_ptr(Sample*, std::_Bind_helper<false, void (MemoryPool<Sample>::*)(Sample*), MemoryPool<Sample>*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type)'`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ updated my post

Comment: unlike `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` has two template parameters, the type to point to and the deleter type.  You only specified the latter while both need to be supplied.

Comment: Maybe related: [Why does unique_ptr have the deleter as a type parameter while shared_ptr doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829576/why-does-unique-ptr-have-the-deleter-as-a-type-parameter-while-shared-ptr-doesn)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for that. I got it corrected by changing it to `std::unique_ptr<Sample, std::function<void(Sample*)>> unq(un->AcquireMemory(), std::bind(&MemoryPool<Sample>::ReleaseMemory, un.get(),
                    std::placeholders::_1));`

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr` doesn't store the deleter type-erased in a shared state block like `shared_ptr`. So you might have to explicitly name the type (or a type it's convertible into)

```
std::unique_ptr<MemoryPool<Sample>> un = std::make_unique<MemoryPool<Sample>>();
std::unique_ptr<Sample,std::function<void(Sample*)>> unq(
    un->AcquireMemory(),
    std::bind(
        &MemoryPool<Sample>::ReleaseMemory,
        memoryPoolPtr.get(),
        std::placeholders::_1
    )
);
```

Bonus meme: just use a lambda instead of `std::bind`

```
auto deleter = [alloc=un.get()](Sample* p){alloc->ReleaseMemory(p);};
auto unq = std::unique_ptr<Sample,decltype(deleter)>(
    un->AcquireMemory(), std::move(deleter)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the other comments/answers pointed out, `unique_ptr` requires *two* template arguments with the 2nd argument being the deleter type.

Another alternative here is to create your own `make_unique_with_deleter` function. The standard `std::make_unique` forwards its arguments to the `T` constructor, so my example here is incomplete.

```
template <typename T, typename D>
auto convert_ptr_to_unique_with_deleter(T* ptr, const D& d)
{
   return std::unique_ptr<T, D>(ptr, d);
}

int main()
{
...

   auto unq = convert_ptr_to_unique(un->AquireMemory(), std::bind(&MemoryPool<Sample>::ReleaseMemory, un.get(),
                    std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

The advantage here is that this will work with any type `T`.